# SQL Insert Datetime temp table truncated error

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to execute this code:

```
DECLARE @temp TABLE (Start dateTime, Name nvarchar)

INSERT  INTO @temp (Start, Name)
VALUES (GETDATE(), 'Callum')

SELECT * FROM @temp
```

and I get this error:

> Msg 8152, Level 16, State 4, Line 3 String or binary data would be
>   truncated. The statement has been terminated.
>
> (0 row(s) affected)

I found out that I'm trying to fit too much data in the column, but I'm not sure how....

Comment: You need to specify the size in `nvarchar` for eg. `nvarchar(50)`

Comment: is that it.... dammit

Comment: NICE ONE!!! damn sql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the size in `nvarchar`. For Eg `nvarchar(50)`